# Sort and backup log4j files

Tags: logs, sort

I apologize for length of this question. It's difficult to explain, even though I was fluent in English, which I'm not ;) 
Not really sure where post this question, because it has java, log4j library and linux.

#### Scenario:

I have several log files (created by log4j using `RollingFileAppender`). Named *file.log* and *file.log.1* to *file.log.10* 
All files are overwritten more than once a day. I mean, if I receive an incidence, I almost sure I have no logs to see what happened, because it would be overwritten.

#### Purpose:

My purpose is to make a backup of these files periodically, with some conditions

- First, do not miss data (solved running a job often enough)
- Do not repeat information. (it would be solved if information was sorted)
- Data must be sorted.  (Problem!!)

#### Considerations:

- Each separate file is sorted, but not all together, because there are two server instances that write to them. 
  I mean that is possible one instance write to *.log.1 and the other *.log.2 at once. So, I cannot merge them all and expect to keep them sorted.
- I can't increase space available on file system.

#### Log register layout:

Each line is like this:

> 2014-11-28 14:33:10,015 main ca.cpy.net.txc.batch.SendEER INFO  - information

#### Attempts:

1. Move from `RollingFileAppender` to `DailyRollingFileAppender` as type of appender. Unfortunately, Apache documentation says

   > "DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization issues and 
   >   data loss".

   So, I can't use it.
2. Use apache log4j extras libraries, but I'm not allowed to do that. It does not depend on me.
3. Do all stuff by myself. It consists in:

   - merge all files
   - sort them
   - discard all saved data in previous backups.
   - compress

   The problem is the sort step. This is what I tried:

   ```
   for ((i=10; i >= 1; i--)); do 
       cat file.log.$i >> $FILE_OUT;  ## put all files in one (as much sorted as possible)
   done;  
   cat file.log >> $FILE_OUT;  ## append last 
   sort -s -t ' ' -k 1.1,1.4n -k 1.6,1.7n -k 1.9,1.10n -k 2.1,2.2n -k 2.4,2.5n -k 2.7,2.8n -k 2.10,2.12n -3k $FILE_OUT -o $FILE_SORTED # Sort by date/time
   ```

   Well, this would work if each register appended to log had one only line (ie: no end-of-line character \n). 
   For example, such sort command above would break a register like this:

   ```
   2014-11-28 14:33:10,015 main ca.cpy.net.txc.batch.SendEER INFO  - 
    ***** RESULTATS ENVIAMENT EXPEDIENT ***** 
       Total documents a tractar en DB: 86
    *****************************************
   ```

   It would sort just first line, and the other three would be put at the beginning of the output file.

Is there a way to sort merged files without breaking each register that contains more than one line? Any other idea will be very welcome, too.

Comment: I'd like to point out that dates of the form `YYYYdMMdDD` can be sorted lexicographically (`d` being some delimiter), so you can sort directly on the first key. The same holds for `HHdMMdSS`, if you use 24-hour format. (so `-k1 -k2.1,2.8`). Can you post a few files (at some pastebin, or on Github) with scrubbed example data, so I can do some trials? Also, if you're on bash: `sort .... file.log.{10..1} file.log -o $FILE_SORTED `

Comment: Is number of lines in each block of text fixed?

Comment: @muru, I will, but I have to hide some information (company policy). It'll take me some time after lunch ;)

Comment: @jimmij: No, it is not fixed. It can contain a summary of some process, an XML, a response from a REST service, etc. There is not pattern.

Comment: It probably mixes the logs together and may not work correctly, but you can try to run parallel `tail -f` for each logfile and append their output to the same output file.

Comment: I uploaded two files, with the conditions I described: Each file is sorted, but not merged: [file.log.1](http://pastebin.com/3HfDtA3r) and [file.log.2](http://pastebin.com/838Lwvhr) <br/> On the other hand, I've been thinking about try to detect each EOL character (\n or \r\n) which is not and end of register, and replace for a weird character. Then, merge, sort (e.g. as @muru said), and replace back to and EOL character by finding weird characters. What do you think?

Comment: @jofel, I'm not sure how to do that. How is that guarantee output file is sorted?

Comment: You cannot guarantee it, but if new log lines are immediately written, you get the ordering automatically due to the different timings. Each `tail -f` waits until the logfile they belong to is changed and writes the new lines to its output. Of course, the tail commands need to run the whole time. It does not work afterwards.

Comment: Ok, I get that, now. I'm afraid I won't be allowed to do that. Besides, I should have a lot of processes concurrently, one per file: I have 11 files per logger, and 5 loggers running 24/7. It's too much.

Comment: @Albert the weird character you're looking for is `\0` (`NUL`). Try something like: `perl -pe 's/\n(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},)/\0$1/' log.file` to replace all newlines just before a date/time stamp with the null character, and the use sort's `-z` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

Make the log files `NUL`-delimited. That is, make every record end with a `NUL` (`\0`) character. Then you can avail of the support for `NUL`-delimited text found in a number of tools (`sed`, `sort`, `xargs`, `find`, etc.). One way could be to do:

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/\0$1/' file.log.2 > file.log.2.NULL
```

- Prepend every timestamp with a `\0` (This is the other way around - making records begin with `NUL`, but in effect...)

Then you can do:

```
sort -szt ' ' -k1,2 file.log{.{10..1},}.NULL -o $FILE_SORTED
```

- `-s` is for a stable sort (so that tied entries are sorted in order of appearance)
- `-z` turns on `NUL`-delimited text support
- I have changed the keys, since as I noted in the comments, timestamps of the form `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS,UUU` are lexicographically sortable. You don't need numeric sort for them.

Or you can avoid all these temporary files altogether:

```
perl -pe 's/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/\0$1/' file.log{.{10..1},} | \    
 sort -szt ' ' -k1,2 -o $FILE_SORTED
```

Comment: At first sight, it looks wonderful. I still have to do some tests and finish the script. I'll let you know.

Comment: One question: The best way to restore, could be `cat $FILE_SORTED | tr -d '\0'`? I'm quite sure there is not other '\0' character elsewhere, but just in case: Is there a way to force that only replace '\0' at the beginning of each line? I'm not able to do it with `sed`.

Comment: Put yet another `perl` at the end of the pipeline: `perl ... | sort ... | perl -pe 's/^\0//' > $FILE_SORTED`, and skip the `-o $FILE..` for `sort`.

Comment: Of course, what was I thinking! Don't know why I was fighting with $1, $2 args to print the rest of each line... I must be tired xD. Thanks.